# Email from a website

Tags: php, email

I'm new at web-site creation , but not beginner at programming. At the moment i'm working at my resume-site (http://mq4me.byethost24.com/). Final thing at my website is Email sending from the "CONTACTS" section.
So before come here i searched this thing during a long of time . I've used phpMailer and mail function in a different ways, but the result remains the same . I GOT NO EMAILS FROM MY WEBPAGE.

how i use [PHPMailer()](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)

```
require("PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php");

    if(isset($_POST[email])){

        $to = "1stallways@gmail.com";
        $usermail = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['title'];
        $message = $_POST['content'];
    }

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From = $usermail;
    $mail->AddAddress($to); 
    $mail->Subject  = $subject;        
    $mail->MsgHTML($message); 

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo 'Message was not sent.';
        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }
?>
```

How i use [mail()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST[email])){

            $to = "1stallways@gmail.com";
            $usermail = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = $_POST['title'];
            $message = $_POST['content'];

            mail($to, $subject, $message, "From".$usermail);
            echo "Thank you.";
    }
?>
```

I used manuals like this, but nothing happens.
Can you advise me something ?

Comment: @jycr753 I believe is saying that he's tried both examples with no success, not that they're both part of the same script.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm sorry for my english . It's not my 1st language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your form...

By placing `</input>` you are setting the value of `$_POST['email']` to nothing... remove `</input>`

```
<input value="Value 1">Value 2</input>
<!-- Value 2 is always chosen by default -->
```

Also you want to change the submit button to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="ctbtn" />
```

[image]

---

On a side note: I saw in some parts of your code, that you would close a `<img>` tag... that is also incorrect... Note, that not all HTML tags need to be closed (google "HTML void elements" to see which ones don't)...

[image]

**Read this:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements**

And look under void elements:

[image]

---

EDIT again...

I just checked your page again... and found that your `require("PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php");` is linked to the wrong place...

You need to change that to: `require("../PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php");`

Comment: I'm googling them at the moment. Thank you very much !

Comment: @Animus no problem... I attached an image of all the void elements to the end of my answer in case you had trouble finding them.

Comment: I edited my form, like you sad. I'm using PHPMailer now, the same way as I posted.

Can you tell me should this code work on your opinion ?? Maybe there are some issues, that I don't know ? Maybe some tools, libraries or just values that I forgot to fill ?

Comment: @Animus add this `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` above `require("PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php");`

Comment: @Animus I think that it can't find the page that you are requiring, but the comment above will print out the errors you are receiving.

Comment: @Animus I think I found out what was wrong, I updated the end of my answer to show it... but just added `../` before `PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php`

Comment: You were right. Now i got the response from php side "Message has been sent.". I had this over 99999 times befor. But I can't understand why the message never comes to me ?? Maybe I'm using PHPMailer wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in this line:

```
if(isset($_POST[email])){
```

should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
```

Otherwise, it will result in an error notice (Notice: Use of undefined constant email).

Comment: not true... proper syntax requires `'` but PHP will still understand what you mean if you leave out the `'`... you might get a 
`Notice: Use of undefined constant email - assumed 'email' in ...`, but it will still work

Comment: @Arian Thanks, I was not aware of that. Still, proper syntax is... you know, proper.

Comment: @larsAnders You should update your answer to reflect that, since it is not evaluated to false.